# Issue with copying Images: My VBA Code is used to sort through a database and copy lines to another sheet but the images are not copied

Tags: excel, vba, image

I successfully wrote a code that sort through a database and looks for parts that need to be made by waterjet technique. Then, copy the associated lines with the waterjet criteria met, to another sheet named "Waterjet". It works fine, but the picture on the source sheet are not copied to the second sheet. I want to get help in finding why the pictures are not follow the cell. I checked and verified that the pictures are set to move and sized by the the cell.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Range("A4:K2000").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Range("D1").Select
i = 4
j = 4
While i <= 2000

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7) = "Waterjet" Then

p = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
q = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
s = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
t = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5)
u = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
v = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7)
w = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8)
x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9)
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10)
Z = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 11)

    Cells(j, 1) = p
    Cells(j, 2) = q
    Cells(j, 3) = r
    Cells(j, 4) = s
    Cells(j, 5) = t
    Cells(j, 6) = u
    Cells(j, 7) = v
    Cells(j, 8) = w
    Cells(j, 9) = x
    Cells(j, 10) = y
    Cells(j, 11) = Z
    
    j = j + 1
    
    Else
End If
i = i + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

[Source Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHf34.jpg)
[Target Sheet - pictures are not copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khtpv.jpg)

**Why the images in cell "q" Cells (i,2) are not copied to cells (j,2) in the other sheet?**

Comment: Because the images (shapes) are not actually *in* the cell. Shapes/images need copied separately.

Comment: in short, images do not "belong" to cells, but rather to the sheet's `Pictures` or `Shapes` collection. You would need to iterate through that collection to get the images

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can you help me to write the code to include the pictures?

Comment: Shapes typically *are* copied along with their underlying ranges.  If that's not happening there's a setting you can try: `Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True`   There's a checkbox for this in the Excel Options dialog.  Do that before the copy/paste operation.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - I just looked at your code and you're not actually copy/pasting anything, which explains why images aren't carried over.

If you also need images the maybe switch to copy/paste instead of setting values.

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, wsData As Worksheet, shp As Shape

    Me.Range("A4:K2000").ClearContents
    'remove any previous shapes
    For Each shp In Me.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp
    Me.Range("D1").Select
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    j = 4
    For i = 4 To wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        If wsData.Cells(i, 7) = "Waterjet" Then
            'adjust the destination row height before pasting
            Me.Cells(j, 1).RowHeight = wsData.Cells(i, 1).Height
            wsData.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 11).Copy Me.Cells(j, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Shapes typically are copied along with their underlying ranges. If that's not happening there's a setting you can adjust before the copy/paste operation:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

There's a checkbox for this in the Excel Options dialog.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tim, I checked this box but the images are still not being placed in the new sheet. I also added the line Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True; but that did not help as well. Can you suggest anything to augment my code?

Comment: It will only work if the top-left corner of the image is within (or not too far out of) the copied range.

Comment: Tim - you are great - answering me so quickly! Thanks. Unfortunately, the pictures in my sorce database are perfectly sized with the cell. If I just do Copy/Paste in Excel, not in VBA, the picture will go with the cell.

Comment: Where are the images located?

Comment: In the code I shared above, the images are in the Column 2. All cells in Cells (i,2) have image.

Comment: Copy/paste with images included is working fine for me.

Comment: Tim, yes.. Copy and Paste the cell with the images work within Excel but not from the VBA. Are you saying that you used the code and it was copying the images?

Comment: I have lots of code in production which does that successfully.  Note - your `ClearContents` will not remove any existing images, so you'll need to add some code for that.

Comment: Tim, thank you. Can you help me to re-write the code properly?

Comment: I just sent yu an email with the file. It will come from neldor@ijwhite.com.

Comment: See edited code above - just replace your existing code with that. Note some of your images overlap slightly with the row below, and get copied along with that row - you should resize so they're entirely within the cell boundaries (and add some padding to be sure)